# Hyperlink style not applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink, styles

I have a list of `Hyperlink` elements in a `ItemsControl` they display correct but their style is not applied for some reason, I cannot figure out why.

Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CE1C37" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#555555" /> 
</Style>
```

How they are displayed:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding DataContext.TopicSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the `Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock}`. The typed style doesn't work otherwise.

IMO you should've received a compiler error.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt seem to make a difference - it only works if I name it

Comment: Be sure there's no `x:Key` in the style definition (just as in your question).

Comment: Hey Jeff - Without any `x:Key` it doesnt work, but if I name it then it does work (so long as I specify the style in the `Hyperlink`)

Comment: I'm finding the opposite - no `x:Key`, only `TargetType` in the style's definition, no `Style` set from `TextBlock` declaration - then it works.

Comment: Interesting and yet odd... Either way you fixed it

Comment: It seems, one problem is that you nested TextBlock's. You may try to set the style of the inner one. Another problem may be that some of your properties are not qualified by `TextBlock` - ie. `Foreground` and `IsMouseOver`.